# Why do I get a PDOException when I try to create the database using Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

First, I would like to mention the issue appears only when I try to recreate the database using `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`.  **All other Doctrine commands work**.

To prove it, let's delete the database:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
Dropped database for connection named `my_database`

Process finished with exit code 0 at 01:59:44.
Execution time: 2 834 ms.
```

However, now, when I try to recreate the database with `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`, I get:

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_database'
```

The doctrine configuration in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

The related arguments in parameter.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: ~
    database_name: my_database
    database_user: root
    database_password: ~
```

List of Doctrine packages:

```
doctrine/annotations              v1.4.0  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                    v1.6.1  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections              v1.4.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                   v2.7.2  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                     v2.5.12 Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle          1.6.7   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle    1.3.0   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 2.3.0   Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle
doctrine/inflector                v1.1.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator             1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                    v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                      v2.5.6  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can appear when using Doctrine DBAL 2.5, as stated in the Symfony documentation:

> The `server_version` option was added in Doctrine DBAL 2.5 ... **If you don't define this option** and you haven't created your database yet, **you may get `PDOException` errors** because Doctrine will try to guess the database server version automatically and none is available.

So we have to define the database server version in `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 5.7
```

To find you server version, you can:

- use `mysql -V` for MySQL
- use `postgres -V` or `psql -V` for PostgreSQL